# Photosynthesis and respiration

Tags: visible-light

I am in 7th grade and am current re-learning photosynthesis again. My question is if plants perform both respiration and photosynthesis, and animals perform only respiration then how come the percentage of oxygen in the air stays about the same? 
If this confused you, here is a simple equation I wrote to explain my question more; Plants: p = photosynthesis, r = respiration, Animals: R = respiration

6p - 6r -6R = total oxygen in atmosphere.

6CO2 + 6H2O ---> C6H12O6 + 6O2 ; Plants only

C6H12O6 + 6O2 ---> 6CO2 + 6H2O + Energy ; Animals only

Comment: Why do you think the amount of oxygen should change? How does your equation show this?

Comment: See [Would oxygen levels be stable without photosynthesis?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21501) in Biology SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a physics question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that animals take oxygen from the atmosphere for cellular respiration. Plants on the other hand, take carbon dioxide from the atmosphere for photosynthesis. During photosynthesis, some of the O2 produced is discarded as a waste product, and glucose (and a small amount of oxygen) is stored in the plant for cellular respiration. The oxygen that plants use for respiration, then, does not come from the atmosphere, but instead from the plant itself. It is important to note that at night, plants will absorb small amounts of oxygen when there is not sunlight. However, the amount of oxygen excreted by plants is way more than the amount absorbed.

In short, the percentage of oxygen in the atmosphere stays the same because animals take in oxygen, and plants excrete it as waste. This causes the amount of oxygen to be the same. Plants do not take in extra oxygen from the atmosphere for cellular respiration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, but do plants still make a waste product of 6 compounds of oxygen, they just store some of it inside them?

Comment: For the respiration equation, it says 6 compounds of oxygen as the input, but you said they only store some of the oxygen to use it later. Are the equations my science teacher gave me incorrect?

Comment: Oh!!!!!!!!! I understand now. The rate of respiration to photosynthesis must be 1 to 6 or something like that so they can store 6 compounds of oxygen to perform respiration.

Comment: The equations are correct; 6 molecules of oxygen are produced as a by-product. Also, you are correct about the ratio of the activities - the rate at which photosynthesis occurs in plants is higher than the rate at which cellular respiration occurs. That means that a relatively small amount of oxygen is stored by plants, while most of the oxygen produced just diffuses out of the plant.  The stored oxygen, along with the absorbed oxygen, is what plants use to conduct cellular respiration.

Comment: Do you know the exact rate of photosynthesis to respiration is?

Comment: I’m not quite sure what the exact rate is, but I think that P:R should be greater than 1. The exact rate would depend on the ecosystem in question and it’s conditions.